# Regex Match all characters after last occurrence (and before first occurrence)

Tags: .net, regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm having trouble figuring out a regex pattern that will match all characters after last occurrence of '<' and before first occurrence '>'.

Here's an example string:
`test1 <test2 <test3> <<test4> test5>>`

the result should be `test4`

I've tried searching but haven't had any luck finding an example close enough to make sense to me.

Comment: How about [`(?![^<]*<)[^>]+`](https://regex101.com/r/KvOdsm/1) (see [this .NET demo](https://tio.run/##XU9NT4NAEL3zK0YuBUVi/ThB0cT0YCIxsUYPTZusMNZNloXszhoM4bcjS8FW5/Lem483M5k@z0qFXWc0lztYfWvCInKOVfiCNYXPuDOCqWVdKdSal1JHjlOZd8EzyATTGpY1KyqBTuNAH2NJE6MevkqeQ8q49Pyhuu@xoUnZVRUjQiVhAXeud3uy3sab09hfb5PNmRv9b@ayMjS0EmqaQ2zhcg9XCcQDuU7Awk2SHBn0X2D9VJG9H8oRF3/SYWoEccElHsZ@Scoo@4RiGgkH7Q33BNMPwWTsHwzue1kKDN8UJ3zsvT131ly0M/gojcyBUf9TjjU089YNoAhfmTBoyYNNj0at03bdDw)) Would that work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this expression: `^.*?<(?=[^<]*$)([^>]+)>.*$`

The first captured group is the text you are looking for, demo: https://regex101.com/r/sUY6x8/2

Logic being, find the last opening bracket (using a lookahead), and then match till a closing bracket

Comment: That matches the whole line

Comment: It does, group 1 is the part you are looking for (this expression consumes the text to find the match)

Comment: there's only one way (that I can think of) which will only match the text needed - but it requires non-fixed length look-behinds (that very few languages support) but in case you are using one that does, see this: https://regex101.com/r/kG3kWw/1 @LorneCash

Comment: I'm using .NET 6

Comment: ah you might be able to use the second demo link expression then

Comment: @LorneCash See [this demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%5e.*%3f%3c%28%3f%3d%5b%5e%3c%5d*%24%29%29%28%5b%5e%3e%5d%2b%29%28%3f%3d%3e.*%24%29&i=test1+%3ctest2+%3ctest3%3e+%3c%3ctest4%3e+test5%3e%3e) of the variable widt [lookbehind-solution from @akash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74539797/regex-match-all-characters-after-last-occurrence-and-before-first-occurrence#comment131580019_74539850), it seems to work.

Comment: My mistake, the second solution did work.